# Recursively flatten a list with streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have tree-like structure with internal nodes and terminal nodes:

```
public interface Node
{
}

public class InternalNode implements Node {
    private List<Node> nodes;
}

public class TerminalNode implements Node {
    private String label;
}
```

I now have a `List<Node>` which I want to flatten. Here, flattening means that I want to replace an internal nodes recursively by its children, until all internal nodes are replaced by terminals.

I came up with this function:

```
private static List<Node> flatten(final List<Node> nodes) {
    return nodes
            .stream()
            .map(node -> {
                if (node instanceof InternalNode) {
                    return flatten(((InternalNode) node).getNodes());
                }
                return Collections.singletonList(node);
            })
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This seems to do its job. However, I am wondering if there is a better implementation possible. It seems odd that I first have to wrap a `TerminalNode` into a singleton list (of type `List<TerminalNode>`) via `Collections.singletonList(node)` and then later I have to convert that singleton list back to the node again via `flatMap(List::stream)`.

Is there a way to avoid this useless `Collections.singletonList(node)` followed by `flatMap(List::stream)` for the terminal nodes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could just use flatMap directly:

```
private static Stream<TerminalNode> flatten(final List<Node> nodes) {
    return nodes
            .stream()
            .flatMap(node -> {
                if (node instanceof InternalNode) {
                    return flatten(((InternalNode) node).getNodes());
                }
                return Stream.of((TerminalNode) node);
            });
}
```

If you want a List, you can just collect the result of that method call.

Comment: …and in a conditional: `.flatMap(node -> node instanceof InternalNode? flatten(((InternalNode) node).getNodes()): Stream.of((TerminalNode) node))`