# List of List of Lists (Flatten a ArrayList with N-Depth)

Tags: java, java-stream, flatmap

I am trying to Flatten a ArrayList with N-Depth. For this I tried using flapMap method of Stream API. I am able to get it. But I have to use flatMap() method repeatedly as per the number of list of lists. If I am using one more flatMap() method, it shows compile time error. Is there any way to dynamically get it done.

This is the code that I used:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(7,8,9);

List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = Arrays.asList(list1, list2);

List<List<List<Integer>>> listA = Arrays.asList(listOfLists);
List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> listB = Arrays.asList(listA);

List<Integer> listFinal = listB.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
//In the above line, If I use listA instead of listB, it is showing error.

listFinal.forEach(x-> System.out.println(x));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670243/recursively-flatten-a-list-with-streams ?

Comment: No, Here they are passing flatten(final List<Node> nodes), But in my case, the input will be dynamic. So I used List<?> list as parameter. But I am unable to convert it to List of Lists inside the method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32656888/1876620 there's a way to do something similar, maybe it serves as a source of inspiration

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me, using recursion. When given a list

- check if it is a list of Integer, in which case return it.
- otherwise it is a list of lists. FlatMap it (to remove 1 level of nesting), and flatten the resulting list.

```
private static List<Integer> flatten(List<?> list) {
    if (list.get(0) instanceof Integer) {
        return (List<Integer>) list;
    }

    List<List<?>> listOfLists = (List<List<?>>) list;
    return flatten(listOfLists.stream()
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<List<List<List<Integer>>>>> listC = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    Arrays.asList(0, 1),
                                    Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4)
                            ),
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    Arrays.asList(5),
                                    Arrays.asList(6, 7),
                                    Arrays.asList(8, 9)
                            )
                    ),
                    Arrays.asList(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    Arrays.asList(10, 11),
                                    Arrays.asList(12, 13, 14)
                            ),
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    Arrays.asList(15),
                                    Arrays.asList(16, 17),
                                    Arrays.asList(18, 19)
                            )
                    )
            ),
            Arrays.asList(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    Arrays.asList(20, 21),
                                    Arrays.asList(22, 23, 24)
                            ),
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    Arrays.asList(25),
                                    Arrays.asList(26, 27),
                                    Arrays.asList(28, 29)
                            )
                    ),
                    Arrays.asList(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    Arrays.asList(30, 31),
                                    Arrays.asList(32, 33, 34)
                            ),
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    Arrays.asList(35),
                                    Arrays.asList(36, 37),
                                    Arrays.asList(38, 39)
                            )
                    )
            )
    );

    List<Integer> result = flatten(listC);

    System.out.println(listC);
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

prints

```
[[[[[0, 1], [2, 3, 4]], [[5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]], [[[10, 11], [12, 13, 14]], [[15], [16, 17], [18, 19]]]], [[[[20, 21], [22, 23, 24]], [[25], [26, 27], [28, 29]]], [[[30, 31], [32, 33, 34]], [[35], [36, 37], [38, 39]]]]]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
```

There is a bit of Unchecked casting going on, but not sure how to do without

Answer (score 0):

For `List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> listB`, `.stream().flatMap(.stream()).flatMap(.stream()).flatMap(.stream()).collect()`

But for `List<List<List<Integer>>> listA`, `.stream().flatMap(.stream()).flatMap(.stream()).collect()`.

See flatMap() count is just one less than the Generic depth.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know that deeply nested *collections* isn't the best way to represent the data and must be avoided (*it's an almost certain indicator of faulty design*). So I'll treat this question as a cryptic puzzle rather than a practical task.

You can achieve that without using recursion. But caution this approach is vicious as well recursion because as well recursive approach it requires to relinquish the ***type safety*** provided by generics (*I've warned that you shouldn't do that in the first place*).

To do that, you need to perform `intanceof` checks in a *loop*. And populate the resulting list of ***row type*** with elements of a *nested list*.

***Note*** :

- contrary to commonly used generic collections like `List<Integer>` which characterized as **covariant** (*i.e. you can assign **only** collection of the **same type** to it*) you're allowed and to assign *anything* to the list of *row type* and to *modify* it as well. Which is an unsafe combination, and hence usage of row type collections is highly discouraged.

The *loop* exits if the first element isn't a *list*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> source =
            List.of(List.of(List.of(List.of(4,5,6), List.of(7,8,9))));

    List<Integer> result = source.stream()
            .flatMap(list -> deepFlatten(list).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println(source);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static List<Integer> deepFlatten(List<?> nestedList) {
    if (nestedList.isEmpty()) {
        return (List<Integer>) nestedList;
    }

    List result = new ArrayList<>();
    List current = nestedList;
    while (current.get(0) instanceof List<?>) {
        for (Object next: current) {
            result.addAll((List) next);
        }
        current = result;
        result = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return (List<Integer>) current;
}
```

**Output**

```
[[[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet worked for me. Thanks for the response all.

List list1 = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);
List list2 = Arrays.asList(7,8,9);

```
    List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = Arrays.asList(list1, list2);

    List< List< List<Integer> > > list = Arrays.asList(listOfLists);
    List< List< List<List<Integer>> > > listB = Arrays.asList(list);
    
    
    //List<Integer> listF = listB.stream().flatMap(x -> x.stream()).flatMap(x -> x.stream()).flatMap(x -> x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    List<Integer> flattenList = (List<Integer>) getList(listB);
    flattenList.forEach(x-> System.out.println(x));
    
    
}
public static List<?> getList(List<? > s) {
    
    if( s.isEmpty() || !( s.get(0) instanceof List) ) {
        return s;
    }
    
    return getList( (List<?>) s.stream().flatMap(x-> ((List)x).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).